# How to generate an alternating range?

Tags: python

I need to search for an item in a list around a given index with in a given radius. Currently I use this function to generate alternating offsets for the search:

```
def generateSearchIndizes(radius):
    for i in range(1, radius + 1):
        yield i
        yield -i
```

The code that does the search looks something like this:

```
for i in generateSearchIndizes():
    if pred(myList[baseIndex + i]):
        result = myList[baseIndex + i]
        break # terminate search when first item is found
```

My question is, is there a more elegant way to generate the search indizes, maybe without defining a special function?

Comment: Ok, this is just an example, and a stupid one at that. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a more elegant way to generate the search indices

I don't think there's a more elegant way. Your code is very simple and clear.

> maybe without defining a special function?

Yes, that's definitely possible.

```
>>> [b for a in ((x,-x) for x in range(1, 10 + 1)) for b in a]
[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6, 7, -7, 8, -8, 9, -9, 10, -10]
```

Comment: Ok, I will stick with the separate function, it is way more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my go at it:

```
from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain(*zip(range(1, 7), range(-7, 0)[::-1])))
[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 5, -5, 6, -6]
```

Adjust as needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a generator expression?

```
for i in (x/2 * (x%2 * 2 - 1) for x in xrange(2, radius*2)):
    print i
```

It is short and fits to your "without defining a special function" requirement...

But, franky, I'd still prefer to use that special function instead - just for the sake of having more clear code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this with an inner loop, instead of creating a funky generator:

```
found = False
for i_abs in range(1, radius+1):
    for i in (i_abs, -i_abs):
        listitem = myList[baseIndex + i]
        if pred(listitem):
             result = listitem
             found = True
             break # terminate search when first item is found 
    if found:
        break
else:
    # handling in case no match found for pred
```

Some other comments:

- you never test the 0'th element
- since you are testing from both left
  and right, you should stop after
  i_abs reaches the halfway mark
- I don't like repeating list indexing operations,
  would rather repeat a variable reference; so I
  lifted out the repeated `myList[baseIndex+i]` and
  assigned it to `listitem`
- you should add some handling in case
  there is no matching element found
- instead of breaking from the inner loop (which
  here requires an extra `found` variable to 
  break out of the outer for loop), you might 
  be better just returning `result` right from the 
  inner loop,

as in:

```
for i_abs in range(1, radius+1):
    for i in (i_abs, -i_abs):
        listitem = myList[baseIndex + i]
        if pred(listitem):
             return listitem
```

Then there is no break management or `found` variable required.

Answer (score 0):

Why alternate -i, i?  Just do:

```
for i in range(-radius, radius+1):
    listitem = myList[baseIndex + i]
        if pred(listitem):
            return listitem
```

Or if you absolutely must approach from front and back to get the outermost pred-matcher, how about:

```
for i in sorted(range(-radius, radius+1), key=abs):
    listitem = myList[baseIndex + i]
        if pred(listitem):
            return listitem
```

If you have to do this often, just build `sorted(range(-radius,radius+1),key=abs)` once and keep it around for future iterating.

If you absolutely must not use the 0'th element, just insert a `if not i: continue` at the start of your loop.

Comment: `sorted(range(-radius,radius+1),key=abs)[1:]` would remove the zeroth element.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to me at least as readable as a separate function -- and arguably more understandable:

```
radius = 3
for outerbounds in ((-r,r) for r in range(1,radius+1)):
    for i in outerbounds :
        print i
# -1
# 1
# -2
# 2
# -3
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own solution, adding a `yield 0` at the start of the generator, is the most straightforward (aka pythonic).

Here's an infinite offset generator with a different algorithm:

```
def gen_offsets():
    offset= 0
    yield offset
    step= 1; sign= 1
    while 1:
        offset+= sign*step
        yield offset
        step+= 1; sign= -sign
```

A more fanciful (aka not-so-pythonic :) way to write the algorithm above is:

```
import itertools as it, operator as op

def gen_offsets():
    steps= it.imap(op.mul, it.count(1), it.cycle( (1, -1) ))
    offset= 0
    yield offset
    for step in steps:
        offset+= step
        yield offset
```